# Python y CIclos Indefinidos Centinelas?

Tags: python

Necesito preguntarles algo. En un ciclo con centinela, o sea, que se coloque un carácter distinguido para salir del ciclo indefinido, `(while)` en python, por qué hay que poner esta línea y que significa, no le encuentro algo lógico.

Espero respuestas.

```
1 - while x <> "*" :
      <cumplir cuerpo del ciclo>
```

Comment: El operador de comparación `<>` es "diferente de" aunque es obsoleto y en Python 3 fue removido y directamente ocasiona un error de sintaxis, debe usarse `!=` en su lugar. Sus orígenes se remontan al lenguaje ABC en el que Guido van Rossum trabajó y que influenció mucho a la hora de crear Python. El resto se define solo `mientras la variable x sea diferente de "*": hacer algo`

Comment: Si no es literal y se trata de un intento de generalización de la estructura de un ciclo `while` entonces solo tener el cuenta que todo ciclo `while` tiene la estructura `while <concidición>` e iterará mientras la condición se evalué como cierta. En este caso `while <variable> <operador> <carácter>` el ciclo itera mientas la condición `<variable> <operador> <carácter>` se evaluada como `True`, por ejemplo `x = "a"`; `while x == 'a':` iterará mientras el valor de la variable `x` sea igual a la cadena `'a'`.

Comment: Bienvenido(a) a StackOverflow! Trata de colocar un ejemplo más descriptivo de tu duda (quizás un ciclo while completo) de esta forma nos facilitas el poder ayudarte. Un saludo!